# Object Defined error in Excel VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm trying to build a script that extracts the first 6 characters of a column (user defined) and either inserts a new column and pastes those results or just pasts those results over an already existing column (User's choice) but I keep getting an object define error (I've marked the line in the code with asterisks).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code

```
 Sub AAC_Extract()
    Dim rng As Range, col As Range, arr
    Dim sht As Worksheet, shet As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the column that contains the Standard Document Number. " & vbNewLine & _
                        " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
                Title:="Select Document Number Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    hdr = MsgBox("Does your selection contain a header?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Header Option")

    Set dest = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the column that you would the AAC to be placed in. " & vbNewLine & _
                        " (e.g. Column B or Column C)", _
                Title:="Select Destination Range", Type:=8)

     If dest Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     Set sht = dest.Worksheet
     Set shet = rng.Worksheet
    'If dest = rng Then
    '    MsgBox "Your Destination Range can not be the same as your Reference Range.  Please choose a valid Destination Range", vbExclamation
    '    Exit Sub
    'End If


     On Error GoTo 0
     yn = MsgBox("Do you want to insert a new column here?" & vbNewLine & _
                        "(Choosing 'No' will replace the current cells in your selected range." & vbNewLine & "All data in this range will be permanently deleted.)", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Destination Range Options")


    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If hdr = vbYes And yn = vbYes Then
        dest.Select
        With Selection
        .EntireColumn.Insert
        End With
        Set col = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, dest.Column), _
                        sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, dest.Column).End(xlUp))
        Set cols = shet.Range(shet.Cells(2, rng.Column), _
                        shet.Cells(shet.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
        'Columns = cols.Column
        'dest.EntireColumn.Insert
        'col = dest.Column
        'cols = rng.Column
        'For i = 1 To LastRow
        'Cells(i, col).Value = Left(Cells(i, cols), 6)
        'Next i
        'For Each c In col.Cells.Offset(0, -1) 'Offset due to the fact that dest moved when a column was inserted
        '    i = c.Row
        '    c.Value = Left(cols.Cells(i - 1), 6) 'Honestly, I'm not sure why I have to subtract 1 from i....i should be the same row as c
        'Next c
        With col
        .Value2 = cols.Value2
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9))
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any `*` Which line is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Brad sorry, about that.  I edited the script to show the asterisks.  I can't think of how else to approach it other than the way I have it commented out.  I think if I can get this part worked out, I can handle writing the code for the other 3 booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely `sht` is null.

You `Dim sht as Worksheet` but never `Set` it to anything. The line of your error is the first line which uses `sht` so it just happens to be the place where the error is brought to your attention.

I would thin you would want to set it to the sheet associated with the `dest` range.

```
set sht = dest.Worksheet
```

You'll need to be careful to not reuse that variable when dealing with `cols` though (you might consider renaming those to be more explicit about what they are doing but that's another matter). In the way you are setting `dest` and `rng` they are not guaranteed to be from the same sheet which would cause problems when setting `col` versus `cols`. You'll get an exception if you try to compose a range with cells on different sheets.

Comment: thank you for that info.  To be honest, I don't fully understand all of that, but I'll keep rereading it until I do.  

I added set sht = dest.worksheet and it got me past the point I was stuck on.

Now it's giving me an error on the final part:

For Each c In col.Cells
                c.Value = Left(Cells(i, cols.column), 6)
            Next c

Do you have any idea why I can't use that syntax?

I set cols as a range and am choosing i and the column number of range cols, right?  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding that.

Comment: The syntax looks fine...Have you used the debugger to look at the value of `cols.column`? What sheet is it pointing to? Use the Locals and Watch windows understand the values of your variables. Keep in mind that `Cells` when used without a reference to a sheet (for example: `Sheets(1).Cells(i,cols.Column)` will reference a range in your Activesheet. Getting around this is called using Fully Qualified references. Every range object (`Range` or `Cells`) is a child object of a sheet. You want to be as explicit as possible about what sheet is the parent sheet. Don't let Excel decide for you.

Comment: @flwr_pwr here's an example of what I mean when I say "the way you are setting dest and rng they are not guaranteed to be from the same sheet which would cause problems when setting col versus cols": `Set dest = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3))` this will throw the exception "Application-defined or Object-defined error". The error makes sense because you tried to compose 1 continuous range from cells on two different sheets. Doing that is not really logical.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation!  I really understand what you mean now and I now understand the .Parent function.

I'm looking at the Local and Watch windows now as I debug the code.  Hopefully this will provide some insight as to why it's erroring out!

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, you can very quickly get the six left-most characters into an entire column by using VBA's [TextToColumn method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213590%28v=office.11%29.aspx), choosing the first field as a width of *6* and discarding any other field. For long columns of values, this should make an appreciable difference over looping and pulling out the first six characters of each cell.

Near the bottom of your supplied code, you have the following loop.

```
    For Each c In col.Cells
        c.Value = Left(Cells(i, cols), 6)
    Next c
```

This would seem to to have **col** defined as the destination of the first six characters from source column **cols**. You loop through every cell and peel off the first six characters.

```
With col
    .Value2 = cols.Value2
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9))
End With
```

This transfers the values from **cols** to **col** then strips off anything past the sixth character all the way through the column at once.

For anything less than a few  hundred values, I don't know if I would bother with the rewrite but the efficiency will increase the more rows of values you have to process.

Snippet Implementation:

```
Sub AAC_Extract()
    Dim rng As Range, col As Range, cols As Range, arr
    Dim sht As Worksheet, shet As Worksheet, hdr As Long, yn As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim dest As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the column that contains the Standard Document Number. " & vbNewLine & _
                        " (e.g. Column A or Column B)", _
                Title:="Select Document Number Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    hdr = MsgBox("Does your selection contain a header?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Header Option")

    Set dest = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the column that you would the AAC to be placed in. " & vbNewLine & _
                        " (e.g. Column B or Column C)", _
                Title:="Select Destination Range", Type:=8)

     If dest Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     Set sht = dest.Parent
     Set shet = rng.Parent

     On Error GoTo 0
     yn = MsgBox("Do you want to insert a new column here?" & vbNewLine & _
                 "(Choosing 'No' will replace the current cells in your selected range." & vbNewLine & _
                 "All data in this range will be permanently deleted.)", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Destination Range Options")


    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If yn = vbYes Then
        dest.EntireColumn.Insert
        Set dest = dest.Offset(0, -1)
    End If

    'I'm not sure about this because the next set starts in row 2 regardless
    'If hdr = vbYes Then
    '    Set dest = dest.Resize(dest.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    'End If

    Set cols = shet.Range(shet.Cells(2, rng.Column), _
                    shet.Cells(shet.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
    Set col = sht.Cells(2, dest.Column).Resize(cols.Rows.Count, 1)

    With col
        .Value2 = cols.Value2
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
          FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9))
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting.  I tried to use the method that you supplied; however, after inserting a new column, the Macro doesn't seem to do anything.  Do you have any ideas as to why that might be?  I have updated the code in the Orignal Post

Comment: @flwr_pwr - I've added the snippet into the full updated code

Comment: that works great!  Thank you so much.  Very efficient.

If you don't mind, could you explain this part of the code:

'FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 9))'

I only  ask because I also have to recreate the function to pull the Mid(7,4) of a range as well and I"d like to use the same methodology.

Unfortunately, after walking myself through the strings of the syntax you provided, it's way over my head.

Comment: I included a link to the [TextToColumn method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213590%28v=office.11%29.aspx) official documentation. Why not start there and come back with *specific* questions if you are having trouble with a concept ?

Comment: will do.  Thanks for all of your help!